# x2go client not showing gui

Tags: 14.04, x2go, x2goclient

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 system with x2goclient version 4.0.1.1 installed.
When I open the client, the GUI doesn't show.

I tried erasing the local settings by running `rm -rf ~/.x2go`, but that didn't help.
Also, when i run `strace x2goclient` I keep getting lines like these:

```
recvmsg(6, 0x7fffc069d220, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(6, 0x7fffc069d3f0, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(8, 0x7fffc069d3e0, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}], 6, 13176
```

What's wrong? What should I do?

P.S. also tried installing newest version from their stable and unstable repositories with no success, same thing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION: after upgrading the version to latest x2go repo version and installing xfce, the window appeared at the edge of the screen.

don't know why it was being drawn outside of the screen in the first place, maybe changing the desktop resolution would have revealed it too.

Comment: This happened on Windows, too.  :(  I uninstalled and reinstalled several times.  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/bring-misplaced-off-screen-windows-back-to-your-desktop-keyboard-trick/ has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it's gone once I install/upgrade xfce4.

Steps:
Install X2Go Server:

```
sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
```

In this case I’m going to access the XFCE4 Desktop of remote Ubuntu server, so also install the Xfce4:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Finally restart the server by running reboot command.

Answer (score 0):

For me, `tmux` was tripping up x2go and causing it to show only a terminal. Making `tmux` not open every time I open a shell seemed to fix things.